# How can I load docker MongoDB with a compatible SSL certificate?

Tags: linux, mongodb, docker, ssl, bitnami

I tried to run [bitnami/mongodb](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/mongodb) with SSL certificates given; however, as I run MongoDB, this warning occurs on startup `"Server certificate has no compatible Subject Alternative Name. This may prevent TLS clients from connecting`

This is a partial of my openssl-san.cnf file:

```ini
[ req_ext ]

subjectAltName = @alt_names

[alt_names]

DNS.1 = localhost

DNS.2 = MongoDB

IP.1 = @my_vps_ip_address
```

Docker compose:

```yaml
  mongodb:
    container_name: mongodb
    image: bitnami/mongodb:latest
    environment:
      - MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME=mongodb # For TLS
      - MONGODB_EXTRA_FLAGS=--tlsMode=allowTLS --tlsCertificateKeyFile=/certificates/mongodb.pem --tlsCAFile=/certificates/mongoCA.pem
      - MONGODB_CLIENT_EXTRA_FLAGS=--tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile=/certificates/mongodb.pem --tlsCAFile=/certificates/mongoCA.pem --tlsAllowInvalidHostnames --host mongodb

      - MONGODB_ROOT_USERNAME=${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME}
      - MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      # - MONGODB_DATABASE=test
      # - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_MODE=primary
      # - MONGODB_REPLICA_SET_KEY=replicasetkey123
      - MONGODB_PORT_NUMBER=25409 # DO NOT CHANGE THE PORT, MONGO REPLICA BREAKS
    ports:
      - ${MONGO_PORT}:25409
    networks:
      - network_mongo
    volumes:
      - ./mongo/certificates:/certificates
      - ./mongo/data:/bitnami/mongodb
    restart: unless-stopped
```